# Wireshark showing HTTP on top of TLS

Tags: tls, http, wireshark

I am seeing an HTTP request on top of SSL in Wireshark. Can anyone explain why?
[image]

Comment: https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL#SSL_dissection_in_Wireshark

Comment: HTTP on top of TLS is HTTPS, i.e. perfectly normal what you see if you decrypt HTTPS traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Looks from the screen that some ssl conversation is not properly encrypted, probably some issue on the server I guess. It would be nice if you could share the pcap for the rest also :)